# Is cuminc the only way to estimate the cumulative incidence function for an event of interest in the presence of competing risk events?

Tags: survival, competing-risks

The `cuminc()` function in R from the package `cmprsk` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cmprsk/cmprsk.pdf) allows us to get an estimation of the CIF for an event of interest in the presence of competing risk events.

Is this the only valid (known to this day) way of estimating the CIF when there are competing risk events? If not, is it the one one should go to by default blindly, or are there situations when it is not advised to go for it?

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate its statistical content. For example, do you have a question about alternate methods for estimating a cumulative incidence function? Might you be asking whether the estimation method used by `cuminc()` differs from that used by the basic [survival package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) or other software, and thus want to know their relative advantages? Note that questions specific to software implementations, apart from their statistical content, are off-topic on this site.

Comment: If I understood well, in survival analysis, either Kaplan-Meier estimator is used (when there are no competing risks) or the estimator from the `cuminc()` function in R (when there are competing risks). But I don't find the name of this second estimator and was wondering if it was the only one that existed.
Is that clearer? In which case I'll edit my question with that.

Comment: For example, you can just model the endpoint as a composite endpoint and then use a multinomial probability for which event occurred. You can also define a parametric model for the intensity process (and martingale dependence) and estimate via maximum likelihood. There are a lot of ways to do this... the Fine Grey method is the Breslow Step Estimator for the Subdistributional cumulative hazard function which of course has the benefit of estimating a very general hazard shape.

Answer (score 1):

The `cuminc()` function in the R [`cmprsk` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=cmprsk) works with the subdistribution of each risk. That's a somewhat tricky concept. AdamO explains it nicely on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/260709/28500):

> The intepretation of this subdistributional hazard function is the instantaneous risk of death from cause 1 given you are either still alive, or you've already died of something else. In effect, it averages across these two possibilities in such a way that a high risk of dying previously from other causes lowers your hazard for that specific failure.

The cumulative incidence sums up the instantaneous subdistributional hazards. That provides a simple way to evaluate the associations of covariates with each of the competing risks, as each event is modeled separately. A downside is that the sum of predicted probabilities over all events can sometimes exceed 1. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/587504/28500) and its links for more details.

An alternative is to work directly with cumulative numbers of each event type, if you aren't modeling covariates, or to do a combined competing risks survival model and work with cumulative hazards from that model. The R survival [competing risks vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) illustrates that approach and compares it against the Fine-Gray subdistribution approach. The sum of probabilities over all events won't ever exceed 1, but the interpretation of covariate coefficients can be more complex as all events are modeled together.

Comment: "The cumulative incidence sums up the instantaneous subdistributional hazards." I don't really understand this. According to the documentation, the `cuminc()` function doesn't use the Fine-Gray model (subdistributional hazards). The `crr()` function does though (It cites Fine JP and Gray RJ (1999) A proportional hazards model for the subdistribution of a competing risk. JASA 94:496-509. whilst `cuminc()` doesn't). `cuminc()` seems to use a nonparametric estimator which name I'm not sure about, but seems to be the default thing to look for when plotting survival curves? Am I wrong?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows the [1988 paper by Gray](https://doi.org/10.1214/aos/1176350951) cited in the `cuminc()` function help page is the earlier, no-covariate, precursor to the later Fine-Gray regression model. It is still based on the "subdistribution" concept rather than cause-specific hazards: "The tests are based on comparing weighted averages of the hazards of the subdistribution for the failure type of interest." Note that Gray is the author of the function and continues to maintain the `cmprsk` package.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I'm sorry, I'm still not 100% sure I understand something: to me, if the survival curves obtained with `cuminc()` were based on the "subdistribution" concept, we wouldn't have a step function but a continuous function, right? I understand, however, that the test which are comparing the curves is based on the subdistribution concept but I still cannot figure out the estimator used to draw the curves if that makes sense. Again, sorry if I look like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows the empirical "subdistribution" for an event type is constructed event time by event time, like a cumulative hazard function, but with an altered risk set that includes contributions from those who have already experienced some other event. In particular, Fine and Gray say (Section 3): "Without censoring... [an] individual who has not failed from the cause of interest by time _t_ is at risk." Thus the empirical subdistribution is a step function, just with different sizes of steps than you would have in a cause-specific model, due to its choice of risk set.

Comment: Ok! Last question, when you say "the cuminc() function help page is the earlier, no-covariate, precursor to the later Fine-Gray regression model", should I refer to the curve drawn with the `cuminc()` function as a Fine-Gray adjusted (for competing risks) survival curve? Or does it have a specific name?

Comment: This paper seems to refer to another estimator for the cumulative incidence function (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9160487/). Do you know how it differs from the `cuminc()` one, or if it's the same? They say it's the `Kalbfleisch and Prentice` one which is also cited in the `cuminc()` documentation.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows There are 2 types of cumulative-incidence curves; see the R [competing risks vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf). The classic Aalen-Johansen method (Section 2.1) shows the probability of being in each state over time. That's presumably what's in the K&P text (predates Gray) and the paper you cite in a comment (I don't have access now.) Fine-Gray shows predicted _subdistribution_ over time. Section 4 of the vignette compares the 2 types. Gray calls it the "subdistribution function" in the help page.