# What is the difference between cuminc and crr?

Tags: r, survival, competing-risks

In this slide (from [A TUTORIAL ON ACCOUNTING FOR
COMPETING RISKS IN SURVIVAL
ANALYSIS](https://khrc.ucsf.edu/sites/g/files/tkssra2416/f/wysiwyg/va_stats_seminar_Scherzer_08May2017.pdf)), there are two ways of plotting the cumulative incidence in a competitive risk setting.

What are the differences? Is the Non-parametric approach equivalent to KM but without its biases regarding competitive risks and Fine-Gray a regression then it draws the curves according to the coefficients?

[image]

Comment: The distinction between a KM-type or Cox-model approach and Fine-Gray subdistribution analysis is outlined in the linked duplicate page. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/588670/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/259694/28500) also cover it. The R [competing risks vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) provides much more detail, with worked-through examples, than we can accommodate on this site. If you still have questions after reviewing those documents, please post a new question specific to what remains unclear.

Comment: `cuminc` is not `KM` (it's a non parametric estimation that takes into account competitive risks) and `crr` not `Cox` (it's Fine-Gray) right? Sorry if I'm not clear, I tried going through the link you provided but did not understand well those concepts.

Comment: The `cmprsk` package is not the only and not always the best way to evaluate competing risks. It's based on a concept of "subdistribution," whose implications and limitations you should try to understand first. In the subdistribution universe `cuminc` is the non-parametric approach and `crr` the semi-parametric Fine-Gray regression method, analogous to KM and Cox.

Comment: With competing risks the Aalen-Johansen extension of KM and Cox regression don't have bias in what they estimate. See the vignette linked above. With competing risks, however, Cox regression coefficients can't readily be interpreted in terms of the probability of experiencing a particular type of event. Subdistribution methods treat each event type separately so that Fine-Gray (FG) coefficients have that simple interpretation. With FG, however, the ultimate probabilities summed over all event types can exceed 1. Understand the strengths and weaknesses before jumping to subdistribution.

Comment: Something I don't understand is that `cuminc` doesn't have `coefficients` at all? It just plots a curve, there's no regression, right? The two seemed mainly different on that matter and I'm not sure I'm right after reading your comments. Sorry I'm quite new to survival analysis

Comment: Yes. The `cuminc()` function is mostly for plots, like KM, and doesn't return coefficients. It's non-parametric, no regression involved, although like KM you can get a _p_-value for overall differences among groups. Competing risks isn't the easiest way to start learning about survival analysis.

Comment: Ok! However, to plot stuff, `crr` uses coefficients right?

Comment: Presumably yes, as the plot method is based on model predictions that involve the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you so much!